# AdMob "We could not find your app in the app store"

Tags: admob, adsense

I am trying to add my iPhone app into admob for a campain.  When I put in the URL to the app store I always get the error "We could not find your app in the app store".  Here is the link I am using (it follows the exact format they suggest):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/minechat-mobile-lite/id604733559?mt=8

I have tried every link combination and format possible.  I have even tried iTunes links to other apps, nothing works.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks